# Unable to find the lib file in ROBOT framework

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\l.logesh\PycharmProjects\roboframewrk> robot r.robot                           
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Users\l.logesh\PycharmProjects\roboframewrk\r.robot' on line 2: Non-existing setting 'Library seleniumlibrary'.
==============================================================================
R
==============================================================================
```

```
robotframework                 6.0.2
robotframework-pythonlibcore   4.1.2
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 6.1.0
selenium                       3.141.0
setuptools                     60.2.0
```

I tried to run this robot testcase. even though i  installed on the machine i getting this error

need to run this robot framework on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

You need two or more spaces after every keywords.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
```